# Existence of coordinate systems for submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I decided to do the following problem as an exercise: Let $p \in M$ be a regular point of $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$. Prove the existence of a coordinate system $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ near $p$ such that $f(x)=f(p)+x_{1}.$

Try: Since $p$ is regular, $Df|_{p}$ is surjective and we get a submanifold near $p$ locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ (by inverse function, submersion theorems). Can someone hint at the choice of charts so that the restriction to this open neighborhood of $p$ gives $f(x)=f(p)+x_{1}.$ Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less the same as the problem at

[coordinate system, nonzero vector field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242767/coordinate-system-nonzero-vector-field?rq=1)

except that the problem there begins with a vector field $X$. That vector field, for you, is just the gradient of $f$. With that starting point, you should be able to turn the rest of the answer into the answer that you need.

Comment: thanks John, i have Let $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$  be smooth and $p \in M$ its regular point. Consider $y_{1} = f(x) - f(p).$ Since $p$ is a regular point, $Dy_{1}|_{p} \neq 0,$ since some component $\frac{\partial f}{x_{i}} \neq 0.$ Thus, we can complete the vectors $$\(Dy_{1}|_{p}, v_{2}, v_{3}, ..., v_{n}\)$$ to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Comment: but at this point, the problem is i don't see what i needs to be shown after this point